# Dynamic Enabled = true in C# chart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

I have a database witch contains values of different tracks.

For example:

***Track 1:***

```
Sensor 1
Sensor 2
Sensor 3
Sensor 4
Sensor 5
Sensor 6
Sensor 7
Sensor 8
```

***Track 2:***

```
Sensor 1 
Sensor 2 
Sensor 3 
Sensor 4 
Sensor 5 
Sensor 6 
Sensor 7 
Sensor 8 
Sensor 9 
Sensor 10 
Sensor 11 
Sensor 12
```

As you can see Track 2 has 12 sensors (Witch is the max!).

Now i want to display the values of the sensors in a graph. Witch is working.

However right now there are 12 items hardcoded. So when there are 8 sensors, the legend will still show 12.

Now what i did was add Enabled = False, so you won't see it. (See example below)

```
<chart:DataSeries x:Name="dsSensor1" Enabled="False" RenderAs="Line" LineThickness="3" LegendText="1" XValueType="DateTime" XValueFormatString="dd-MM HH:mm" YValueFormatString="#0.##'V'" MarkerEnabled="False">
    <chart:DataSeries.DataPoints>
        <chart:DataPoint XValue="2001-01-01" YValue="3.2" Enabled="False"/>
    </chart:DataSeries.DataPoints>
</chart:DataSeries>
<chart:DataSeries x:Name="dsSensor2" Enabled="False" RenderAs="Line" LineThickness="3" LegendText="2" XValueType="DateTime" XValueFormatString="dd-MM HH:mm" YValueFormatString="#0.##'V'"  MarkerEnabled="False">
    <chart:DataSeries.DataPoints>
        <chart:DataPoint XValue="2001-01-01" YValue="3.2" Enabled="False"/>
    </chart:DataSeries.DataPoints>
</chart:DataSeries>
```

Right now you won't see the legend.

Now i the code i made a new loop like this:

```
foreach (DCHistory item in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(t => t.SensorNumber).Take(1))
```

This will take the highest number of a specific track. For example this query will result in **8**.

What i do right now then =

```
    foreach (DCHistory item in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(t => t.SensorNumber).Take(1))
    {
        DataSeries series1 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor1"));
        DataSeries series2 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor2"));
        DataSeries series3 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor3"));
        DataSeries series4 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor4"));
        DataSeries series5 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor5"));
        DataSeries series6 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor6"));
        DataSeries series7 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor7"));
        DataSeries series8 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor8"));
        DataSeries series9 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor9"));
        DataSeries series10 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor10"));
        DataSeries series11 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor11"));
        DataSeries series12 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor12"));
        int sensor = item.SensorNumber;
        if (sensor == 8)
        {
            series1.Enabled = true;
            series2.Enabled = true;
            series3.Enabled = true;
            series4.Enabled = true;
            series5.Enabled = true;
            series6.Enabled = true;
            series7.Enabled = true;
            series8.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

This code will count if the result is 8. If it is 8 enable the first 8 items in the legend.

Now this is working. However i also need to make one for like 12 sensors, or 6.
This will result in a lot of code and still it's **hardcoded**!

> **My question:**

Is it posible to make this in a for loop?

I have tried it already but was unsuccesfull...

What i tried:

```
foreach (DCHistory item in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(t => t.SensorNumber).Take(1))
            {
                int sensor = item.SensorNumber;
                int sensor2 = sensor + 1; //set +1 because if number = 0, it gives error.
                if (sensor >= 1)
                {
                    for (int number = 1; number < sensor2; number++)
                    {
                        DataSeries series = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor{0}", number));
                        series.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The result of this code is that the legend shows me 12 sensors even when there are 8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALright, i have got the awnser!

I think that once i visited a track with 12 sensors, it kept the sensor on Enabled = true.

So whenever i visited a Track with 8 sensors, the old one kept enabled.

What i did now:

```
        foreach (DCHistory item in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(t => t.SensorNumber).Take(1))//Gets highest sensor number of the track
        {
            var sensor = item.SensorNumber + 1;//Gets the number we just asked from the loop. For example 8 or 12.
            var start = 1;
            var max = 12;

            while (start < sensor)
            {
                var test = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor{0}", start.ToString()));
                test.Enabled = true;
                start++;
            }
            if (sensor < max)
            {
                while (sensor <= max)
                {
                    var test2 = chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == string.Format("dsSensor{0}", sensor.ToString()));
                    test2.Enabled = false;
                    sensor++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically i made a check that if the sensor count is 8 for example. It would check if it's lower then the maximum. If it is lower, then disable the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I will transform your code to use some `Linq` instead.

```
var series = Enumerable.Range(1, item.SensorNumber)
    .Select(i => chart.Series.First(s => s.Name == ("dsSensor" + i)))
    .ToArray();

for(var i = 0; i < series.Length; ++i){
    series[i].Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: When i put this in the loop i have (The one where i take 1 result). I get the exact same results as my last example. And that is that i get 12 sensors while i only have 8

Comment: @Mitch Try with this latest version (I was still on grace period), now it only  retrieves 8 instances of the series

Comment: I put it inside this loop: 

foreach (DCHistory item in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(t => t.SensorNumber).Take(1))

However still always returns 12 :/

Comment: @Mitch Seems to me that you will need to debug it yourself then, or include details in your question that you didn't.